# What did -mountedLocalVolumePaths and -mountedRemovableMedia do in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Currently working on porting some deprecated code from on old OS X project I've inherited and haven't been able to find any documentation on what these methods did.

```
[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] mountedLocalVolumePaths ] ]
[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] mountedRemovableMedia ] ]
```

I do know that `- mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:` is the new method, but not knowing exactly what the old methods did (and Apple helpfully removing their documentation), means I'm not sure what options to use to get the right behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is still available in `NSWorkspace`, although it's a bit sparse.

On OS X, a "local volume" is any volume backed by physical media (as opposed to network volumes). So an internal or external hard drive, CD, or DVD, for example, would be a "local volume". Disk images would also be local volumes. These volumes would all be returned by `mountedLocalVolumePaths`. On the other hand, SMB or WebDAV shares would not be "local".

A "removable media" volume is one backed by removable media, for example, a CD or DVD. These are also local volumes, but not all local volumes are removable, of course (for example, internal hard drives are not removable media). `mountedRemovableMedia` would return these removable volumes.

Comment: thanks. yeah I noticed later that apple was hiding the deprecated methods for some reason.